# Ошибка err_connection_reset при отправке файла

Tags: python, django, nginx

Пытаюсь отправить текстовый файл с содержанием "&&&" + любой символ
на сервер через django admin возникает ошибка ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
Если в файле отправить любой другой текст, то все успешно отправляется

Вопрос почему такое может происходит?

Происходит при отправке файла при использовании django admin.

```
class TestDjangoModel(Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=folder_directory_path, 
    help_text=desc.did_list.help_text,  blank=True)
    report_to_jira = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class TestDjangoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestDjangoModel
        exclude = exclude_serializer([])

class TestDjangoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestDjangoModel

class TestDjangoAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["file", "report_to_jira"]
    serializer = TestDjangoSerializer
    form = TestDjangoForm
```

Заметил что локально не воспроизводиться, только на сервере.
Развёрнуто по классике nginx+gunicorn+wsgi+gjango

UPD

Ни в логах nginx, ни в логах gunicorn (собственно логи самой django) ошибок нету

UPD

В access.log просто 400 ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без кода подсказать очень сложно: [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Согласен добавил, там стандартная админка django)

Comment: Если у вас перед django стоит nginx и если появляется ошибка ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, значит соединение обрывает именно nginx и django тут вообще ни при чём. Что в access.log?

Comment: Код добавил на всякий случай) 
Тоже склоняюсь к nginx, но в логах просто 400 ошибка

Comment: Если 400, значит эта ошибка должна была успешно вернуться в браузер без всяких там RESETов. Что-то странное происходит

Comment: Да, определённо странное) На apache сервере ошибка точно такая же, значит что-то разрывает соединение до nginx/apache ?